# Reorder comma-separated fields

Tags: centos, text-processing, regular-expression

I have a text file on Linux server Centos 7 which include a lot of entries in the following format:

```
Test Test, 1234567890123456, a, b, cde
```

and I would like to reorder this to the correct the format:

```
1234567890123456, a, b, cde, Test Test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS = ", *"; OFS = ", " } { print $2, $3, $4, $5, $1 }' file
1234567890123456, a, b, cde, Test Test
```

The `awk` script starts by defining the input field separator (`FS`) to be a comma followed by any number of spaces, and the output field separator (`OFS`) to be a comma and a space.

It then goes on to simple output the input fields in the correct order.